# Find groups containing several rows matching condition

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('AAAAAABBBBBCCCCCC'),
                   'B':list('EFGHIJEGHJKGHJKEI')})
```

```
|    | A   | B   |
|---:|:----|:----|
|  0 | A   | E   |
|  1 | A   | F   |
|  2 | A   | G   |
|  3 | A   | H   |
|  4 | A   | I   |
|  5 | A   | J   |
|  6 | B   | E   |
|  7 | B   | G   |
|  8 | B   | H   |
|  9 | B   | J   |
| 10 | B   | K   |
| 11 | C   | G   |
| 12 | C   | H   |
| 13 | C   | J   |
| 14 | C   | K   |
| 15 | C   | E   |
| 16 | C   | I   |
```

I would like to find all the elements in `A` where `B` contains "G", *and* "H", *and* "I"

therefore, the result should be

```
|    | A   | B   |
|---:|:----|:----|
|  2 | A   | G   |
|  3 | A   | H   |
|  4 | A   | I   |
| 11 | C   | G   |
| 12 | C   | H   |
| 16 | C   | I   |
```

For the moment, I have found the following solution, but that seems overly hackish and I feel I'm missing something obvious

```py
hit = list('GHI')
out = df[df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: (x['B'].isin(hit))&(x['B'].isin(hit).sum()==len(hit))).values]
```

Comment: because B had G and H, but not I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two conditions:

1. *hit* is a subset of the group: `x['B'].isin(hit).sum()==len(hit)`
2. the value at *B* is contained in *hit*: `x['B'].isin(hit)`

So you can express both conditions like this

```
hit = frozenset('GHI')
print(df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(hit.issubset) & df['B'].isin(hit)])
```

**Output**

```
    A  B
2   A  G
3   A  H
4   A  I
11  C  G
12  C  H
16  C  I
```

The expression:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(hit.issubset)
```

is the equivalent of condition 1.

Comment: Thanks! I chose this answer because I did not think of using a `set`. This solution seems more "readable" to me

Answer (score 2):

This transformation isn't that obvious, but we can keep it vectorized by checking the size of each group compared to `hit`:

```
d = df[df['B'].isin(hit)]
size = d.groupby('A').size()
grps = size[size.eq(len(hit))].index

d[d['A'].isin(grps)]
```

```
    A  B
2   A  G
3   A  H
4   A  I
11  C  G
12  C  H
16  C  I
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `groupby` + `filter`

```
hit = list('GHI')
out = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x : pd.Series(hit).isin(x['B']).all())
out = out[out.B.isin(hit)]
out
Out[308]: 
    A  B
2   A  G
3   A  H
4   A  I
11  C  G
12  C  H
16  C  I
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way: First remove those not in `hit`, then filter those that have all `hit`

```
(df[df['B'].isin(hit)]
   .drop_duplicates(['A','B'])
   .loc[lambda x: x.groupby('A')['A'].transform('size')==len(hit)]
)
```

Or similar idea with `groupby().filter`:

```
(df[df['B'].isin(hit)]
   .groupby('A')
   .filter(lambda x: x['B'].nunique()==len(hit))
)
```

Output:

```
    A  B
2   A  G
3   A  H
4   A  I
11  C  G
12  C  H
16  C  I
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method of doing this with boolean indexing without using `groupby` and using `unstack` -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('AAAAAABBBBBCCCCCC'),
                   'B':list('EFGHIJEGHJKGHJKEI')})


filt = df['B'].isin(hit)

df['C']=1
df[filt & df['A'].isin(df[filt].set_index(['A','B']).unstack('B').dropna().index)]
```

```
    A   B   C
2   A   G   1
3   A   H   1
4   A   I   1
11  C   G   1
12  C   H   1
16  C   I   1
```